# Can I proxy mumble traffic from IPv4 to IPv6 with socat?

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv6, ipv4, socat, mumble

I have an IPv6-only Mumble server at home (because I have no public IPv4). I want to make it accessible to IPv4-only users with a small VPN.

- The VPN has a public IPv4 that I can ping
- The VPN has IPv6 connectivity, and it can ping my IPv6 server under its domain name
- The Mumble server can be connected to by people outside my network using IPv6

I tried running these two commands:

```
   socat TCP4-LISTEN:64738,fork,su=nobody TCP6:mumble.mydomain.tld:64738
   socat UDP4-RECVFROM:64738,fork,su=nobody UDP6-SENDTO:mumble.mydomain.tld:64738
```

The VPN is listening on TCP and UDP port 0.0.0.0:64738 according to `netstat`. However, when entering the VPN's IPv4 as Mumble server, it doesn't work (Connection timed out).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a simple oversight - in addition to the VPN firewall rules, I needed to punch holes in the debian-internal `ufw` as well.